# Do I need to release local variables?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

In my app I have a NSError that I declare locally:

```
NSError *error;
```

Do I release it in dealloc method or do I need to release it in the method I declare it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the [Cocoa Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/), memory management is something you should understand perfectly. (And it’s not hard.) If you declare a variable in a method, you don’t have a pointer to it in `dealloc`, therefore you can’t release it there – you can only release it before it goes out of scope. Another question is if you should release it at all. That depends on whether it is a stack-based, autoreleased or retained variable:

```
float foo[] = {1, 2, 3}; // stack-based, no releasing necessary
NSString *foo = [NSString stringWithFormat:…]; // autoreleased, you must not release it
NSString *foo = [[NSString alloc] initWith…]; // retained, you must release it
```

Comment: Thank you - thats the answer I needed

Answer (score 2):

You need to `release` it locally -- assuming you create it by `alloc`/`new`/`copy` or else `retain` it. (If you just get it from somewhere else without allocating or retaining, then it doesn't belong to you and you shouldn't release at all.)

Otherwise, once it goes out of local scope you have no access to the pointer and the object will leak.

Answer (score -1):

You need to release it locally. Because in dealloc method we release class variables or class data members and those variables that are used through out the implementation file (like extern variables).

Comment: This is not a good way to put it. You only need to release the object locally if you own it, which is usually not the case with `NSError`.

Comment: But you cant release it in dealloc method as it is not accessible there. Better to release it in local method. As NSError is used when an error comes. So it totally depends on the situation.

Comment: There are two parts to the question: Where to release and *if to release at all*. You say to release locally (which is fine), but the remaining point is that you almost never need to release `NSError` values at all, since they are autoreleased.

Comment: After trying to release it locally - the app gets interrupted. The same is with other locally declared objects. Seems as though out of NSFileManager, NSError, NSArray and NSString if you declare them locally you only need to release NSFileManager.

Comment: @sregorcinimod, the difference is not in scope (local vs. instance variables), but in memory management (retained vs. autoreleased objects). It’s of paramount importance for you to learn proper memory management (as described in the guide I linked to), otherwise you will suffer.

Comment: @zoul - thanks I had read the link you posted previously but the penny hadn't dropped fully. Your 3 lines of code above made the penny drop.